# ada syntax issues

Tags: ada

I'm new to ada, I want to define a vector package and to be able to pass it to a method, where should I define the package, this is the code I need

```
package Document is new Ada.Containers.Vectors(Positive,Unbounded_String);
use Document;
```

I don't know where to put so it'll be visible to the main and another function file.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using GNAT (either the [GPL version from AdaCore](http://libre.adacore.com/), or the FSF GCC one), you need a file `document.ads` (in the same working directory as you are going to put your main program and the other file).

Your new package `Document` needs to ‘`with`’ two other packages: `Ada.Containers.Vectors` and `Ada.Strings.Unbounded`.

You can’t put `use Document;` in `document.ads`; it needs to go in the packages that make use of `Document` by `with`ing it. The `use` clause controls whether you need to write the fully qualified name - so, for example, to write `Document` as you have it you would say

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded; use Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
package Document is new Ada.Containers.Vectors (Positive, Unbounded_String);
```

but it would be more conventional to write

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
package Document is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
  (Positive,                                                
   Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);
```

Your main program and other packages can now say `with Document;` (and, if you want, `use Document;`).

Answer (score 3):

Additional to the answer by Simon, you can put the two lines you stated anywhere into a [declarative part](http://rm.ada.cx/12a/AA-3-11.html#S0086). This can be inside a Subprogram like your main procedure, a library or anywhere else.

Example for main procedure:

```
with Ada.Containers.Vectors;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;
procedure My_Main is
   package Document is new Ada.Containers.Vectors
     (Positive,
      Ada.Strings.Unbounded.Unbounded_String);
   -- use it or declare other stuff...
begin
   -- something...
end My_Main;
```

To use it across multiple source files, put it into one of your packages or into a separate file like Simon wrote.

Answer (score 2):

In Addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10616130/571138), to actually declare the vector you would need to put in a declaritive section :

```
my_document : document.vector;
```

Then you can use the methods described in the vector [package](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ada_Programming/Libraries/Ada.Containers.Vectors)